# $\frac{d}{dt} (A+t B)^p\,\text{ for } p\geq 1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Given two positive self-adjoint operators $A,B$ on a Hilbert space. Let $p\geq 1$.

I would like to calculate $$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (A+tB)^p,$$

where the power is defined through the spectral theorem. The difficulty is that $A$ and $B$ do not commute in general. Is there a nice formula for that? 
I thought about using some integral representation of $x^p$, which hopefully would make the differentiation easier, but I was not successful.

**Update:**
Thanks for your answers. In my case, I actually only need it for $p\in [1,2)$. Using $y^p = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty dx \,\frac{y^2 x^{p-2}}{x+y}$, I thought about writing $C:=A+tB$ as $$C^p = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty C^2 x^{p-2} (x+C)^{-1} dx.$$
That might also work. I am still happy about other suggestions.

Comment: the general approach is outlined here: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S089547989528274X --- for integer $p$ the answer is easy, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553609/is-there-a-general-form-for-the-derivative-of-a-matrix-to-a-power

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, one standard approach would be to consider the map $A \mapsto A^p$ for any $p$. Then, actually write the map as $A \mapsto \exp(p \log A)$. Then, the derivative that you are after is the Fréchet derivative in direction $B$. This does not look entirely clean, but at this point it is just the chain rule (e.g., see [the derivative of the matrix exponential here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), and of the [matrix logarithm (see Slide 38)](http://www.6ecm.pl/docs/Higham.pdf); also in the same slides, you'll see numerical procedures for computing these derivatives numerically efficiently).

Alternatively, check out the [Daleckii-Krein theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=KHrHCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA120&ots=SC2Eo-P2WZ&dq=daleckii%20krein%20theorem&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=daleckii%20krein%20theorem&f=false), which will show you how to obtain "nice" closed forms for derivatives of matrix functions similar to those in the above question.

Answer (score 4):

I give you the answer in the finite dimensional case, and let you adapt it to the Hilbert space case. Let $f$ be an analytic function; in your case $f(t)=t^p$.

First of all, choose an orthonormal basis in which $A=:D$ is diagonal. Then form the matrix
 $f^{[1]}(D)\in{\bf M}_n({\mathbb C})$ by
$$f^{[1]}(D)_{jk}=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
f'(d_j), & k=j, \\ \\ \frac{f(d_j)-f(d_k)}{d_j-d_k}, & k\ne j,\end{array}\right.$$
where we identify
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}:=f'(a),$$
if $b=a$. Then the differential of $H\mapsto f(H)$, taken at $D$, is
$${\rm D}f(D)B=f^{[1]}(D)\circ B,
$$
where $A\circ B$ denotes the Hadamard product.

**Edit**. As noticed by Suvrit, this is Daleckii-Krein Formula.

Comment: This is essentially the content of the Daleckii-Krein theorem  :-)

Comment: @Suvrit. Thanks. I didn't remember the name of this formula.